# Why attempting to dismiss UIAlertController too early does not dismiss the Alert

Tags: ios

I just realized that calling dismiss on alert controllers too early causes them to not get dismissed. For example, if I present the alert controller and then immediately try to dismiss it, the dismission is just ignored. For example

```
// Done in viewDidLoad
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Connecting to Bubble Centerpiece...\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With this code, AlertController is not being dismissed. In my case, my dismissed was usually being called in about 0.5 seconds after the alert controller was presented and it did not get dismissed. I had to manually delay the dismission code like this to make it work.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: { self.alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)})
```

My assumption is that alert controller takes some time to be set up properly and if the dismiss call arrives earlier than the alert is actually displayed, then it will not be dismissed. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this instead of just delaying it with DispatchQueue.

Comment: What reason do you have for presenting and immediately dismissing an alert? One possible solution would be to create a custom UIAlertController which dismisses itself in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: You can try to dismiss it in the completion block

Comment: Alert is being presented when I enter the activity and remains active until I receive notification that Bluetooth connection was established. Establishing Bluetooth communication takes anywhere from 0.5 up to 4 seconds sometimes. This is the reason why the dismiss call is made fast sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, as long as you pass `animated: true`, the alert controller will not be in the hierarchy until it is done animating, so you can't dismiss it until then. This is precisely what the `completion` block is used for (generally, any good API where things happen *asynchronously* will provide you a completion block to let you know when that action is complete). You can dismiss immediately after presenting (though I don't imagine this is a valuable real-life use case) by doing:

```
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: { 
    alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```